# If all convex combinations of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have real roots, then $p,q$ have a common interlacing poly

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

I heard this result in a talk the other day:

*Suppose $p$ and $q$ are polynomials. Suppose $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and $q$ a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Call $q$ an **interlacer** of $p$ if the roots $a_i$ of $p$ and $b_i$ of $q$ are such that*

$$a_1 \leq b_1 \leq a_2 \leq b_2 \leq \dotsb \leq b_{n-1} \leq a_n.$$

*Suppose $a,b$ are polynomials of the same degree such that $\lambda a(x) + (1-\lambda )b(x)$ has only real roots for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Then $a$ and $b$ have a common interlacing polynomial.*

I've been thinking about how to prove this. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think I went to a talk by the same person.  Anyway, I think he wrote about it here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3969  If you google "Kadison Singer" you might find other web sites that also explain it.

Comment: Just curious: does the result have to see with the sort of homotopy between $a(x), b(x)$?

Comment: The talk was really good.  At the time I felt I understood every word.  But then when I got home, I realized that it was a kind of illusion.  It was a talk that had me sitting on the edge of my seat.  You will have to read the paper yourself.  I think it is Lemma 3.4.

Comment: Also, if someone reads the paper, and then gives an explanation of it here that is understandable, that person will certainly deserve millions of upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

As Stephen Montgomery-Smith says in the comments, this is Lemma 3.5 in [Marcus-Spielman-Srivastava](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3969). They credit it to several different sources, of which [Dedieu (Theorem 2.1)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499290060S#) is the earliest and [Fell (Theorem 2')](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102779366) is to my mind the clearest. Fell also has the advantage of being freely available online.
Here is another presentation of Fell's argument, which handwaves a few "geometrically obvious" details, but seems pretty to me.

For simplicity, assume that $a$ and $b$ have no roots in common. Set $h(x) = \frac{b(x)}{b(x)-a(x)}$. So $x$ is a root of $\lambda a(x) + (1-\lambda) b(x) =0$ if and only if $\lambda = h(x)$. Let $\Gamma$ be the graph of $h$ in the horizontal strip $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$. By hypothesis, for every $\lambda \in [0,1]$, the graph $\Gamma$ crosses the line $\mathbb{R} \times \{ \lambda \}$ at $n$ points. Let those $n$ points be $r_1(\lambda)$, $r_2(\lambda)$, ..., $r_n(\lambda)$. Let $I_k = \{ r_k(\lambda) : \lambda \in [0,1] \}$. In other words, $I_k$ is the interval beneath the arc of $\Gamma$ from $(0,r_k(0))$ to $(1, r_k(1))$.

We claim that the intervals $I_1$, $I_2$, ..., $I_n$ are disjoint. Suppose to the contrary that $x \in I_i \cap I_j$. Then the vertical line $\{ x \} \times \mathbb{R}$ meets $\Gamma$ twice, so $\Gamma$ violates the vertical line test.

So the closed intervals $I_j$ are disjoint. Choose $n-1$ points $s_1$, $s_2$, ..., $s_{n-1}$ with $s_j$ separating $I_j$ and $I_{j+1}$. Then the polynomial $\prod (x-s_j)$ interlaces all the polynomials $\lambda a(x) + (1-\lambda) b(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

---

Interlacing means this. Say we have $A$, $B$ finite disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, with cardinalities differing by at most $1$ :  $|\#A - \#B | \le 1$. We call them interlacing if between any two elements of $A$ there is an element of $B$ ( check this is equivalent to : between any two elements of $B$ there is an element of $A$).

Now, $A$, $B$ of cardinality $n$ have a common interlacing of cardinality $n-1$  ( equivalent to: $\exists$ common interlacing of cardinality $n$ -- just to get familiarized with the concept) if and only if :

if we write $1$ above elements of $A$, $-1$ over elements of $B$. The sum of numbers starting from the left ( or right) is always $\le 1$ in absolute value. So $(1,-1,-1,1)$ is OK, $(1,1,-1,-1)$ not. (note that neither are interlacing).

So this is the combinatorial description.

---

Now, our polynomials $P$, $Q$ have leading term of same sign ( better be, otherwise a convex combination will have degree $n-1$). So we may assume them monic. Also we assume that they both have all real distinct roots.

First, a basic lemma. Assume that $R$ monic, $\deg R = n-1$, and  interlaces $P$. Then we have the partial fraction expansion

$$\frac{P(x)}{R(x)} =  (x-\alpha) - \sum _{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{b_i}{x-\beta_i}$$

with $\beta_i > 0$, $i=1, n-1$. ( the converse is also true).

The proof is fairly basic. Note that RHS is increasing on every interval in the domain.

Now assume that $R$ (monic) interlaces $P$, and $Q$. Write the corresponding equalities for the fractions and take the convex combination. Now it should be clear from looking at graphs.

---

We've taken care of the sufficiency. Let's show necessity. The way to show is this. If the roots of $P$, $Q$ do not satisfy the combinatorial condition above, then the function

$$\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$$

takes some negative values in the upper half plane. This is all looking at arguments of complex numbers. So as a good exercise show that for some $z$ in the upper half plane the argument of the number

$$\frac{(z-3)(z-4)}{(z-1)(z-2)}$$
is exactly $\pi$.

---

As an application, one can show ( with the easy implication) that if for a polynomial $P(x)$ the equations $P(x)-a$, $P(x)-b$ have all roots real, then the same is true for all $c\in [a,b]$. Indeed, the polynomials $P(x)-a$, $P(x)-b$ have a common interlacer $P'(x)$.

Having a common interlacer is "the relation $R\circ R$, where $R$ is the relation "interlace".

In fact "interlace" for $P(x)$, $Q(x)$ polynomials ( of same degree) is equivalent to $\lambda P + (1-\lambda) Q$ has all real roots for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. It is also equivalent to
$$P(x) + i Q(x)$$ has all roots in one of the (upper of lower) half planes ( one should do an engineer check to see which way it goes with respect to interlacing).

Interlacing for polynomials can be checked effectively with the decomposition into a finite (Gauss) continued fraction. Some coefficients have to be negative. It would be interesting to see a decision process for existence of common interlacer.  Yes, we have the $\lambda P + (1-\lambda) Q)$ criterion, but it seems not so easy to apply in the literal case.